# Uploading file through node request using AWS S3 pre-signed url

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to upload a file to an AWS S3 Bucket using a pre-signed url and node request.

My relevant code looks like this:

```js
const name = file.split('/').slice(-1)[0]

const { uploadUrl } = await request.post(requestUploadUrl, {
  body: {
    name,
    repo,
    branch,
    type: contentTypes[name.split('.').slice(-1)[0]],
  },
  json: true,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`,
  },
})

try {
  await request({
    url: uploadUrl,
    method: 'put',
    formData: { [name]: fs.createReadStream(file) },
  })

  console.log(`Uploaded ${file}`)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

The `requestUploadUrl` is a remote url (created by me).

File upload works fine if I manually do it in Postman.

When I run this script all files get prefixed with these headers:

```
----------------------------920900176793713318627065
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file.html"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Which shows in the webpage when I try to download and render the HTML.

Uploaded video files don't work because of these headers.

I would like to get the files without those headers INSIDE the file, but not sure how.

Comment: Those "headers" are `formData`.  Figure out how to upload binary data instead, and you have your solution.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That's it! I was looking at `formData` all the time from the `request` documentation, all the suggestions for file sending pointed there. I changed `formData` to `body: fs.readFileSync(file)` and it worked. Thanks.